# Want to create arrow with CSS

Tags: css

Today i am creating arrow with css. I tried

```
    .arrow-down {
        width: 0; 
        height: 0; 
        border-left: 400px solid transparent;
        border-right: -100px solid transparent;
        border-top: 300px solid #f00; 
    }
<div class="arrow-down"></div>
```

But every time i get  [image]
What i do for next image.
My Question is totally different where i am creating triangle where triangle is not moving after 90 degree.
[image]

Comment: take a look at http://cssarrowplease.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or cover your arrow with another "white" one with :after like this:

```
.arrow-down:before {
    content:' ';
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    top:-300px;
    right:0;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
    border-top: 300px solid white; 
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/38mc0f62/3/)**

Comment: And here We are. Someone downvoting my answer with no comment whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by

1. Create arrow
2. rotate the arrow by transform css rule

```css
.arrow-right {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 120px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 120px solid transparent;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-59deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-59deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(-59deg);
  border-left: 69px solid green;
  margin-left: 170px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-right"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easyers way to create that shape would be with SVG.

Creating a path with svg is not hard.

Just place cordinats in a path `p=m 10 10 100 0 40 100 Z` Where m starts the path and z closes it.

```css
.test {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  //border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<svg class="test" viewbox="0 0 150 150">
  <path d="m 10 10 100 0 40 100 Z" stroke="black"/>
</svg>
```